# How to use loaders in Vite?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vite

in webpack we are able to use inline loader concept:
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/
for example

```
require(`!raw-loader!sass-loader!@/extensions/main.scss`).default
```

will return just compiled string css from scss file.
How can I implement that in vite?

Comment: Just complie in main.js file: `import './scss/main.scss'`

Comment: thank you, am I able to import scss file into index.html using ejs?

Comment: No. scss need to be complied to css